# Include slider in one of the column

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[how can i add slider in one of the column(i.e. video column). I have amazing slider but i failed to show that in column. I am a beginner and a learner. Your help will be appreciated. Thank You](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7BWB.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">


            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-7 hero-feature">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="images/one.jpg" style="
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Videos</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-7 hero-feature">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img src="images/one.jpg" style="
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>HSE Resource</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [quickstart](https://amazingslider.com/how-to-insert-multiple-jquery-sliders-to-one-web-page/) of amazingslider, everything you need is to first create your slider(s) and then implemant it into the HTML.

For your example you should do something like

```
<div id="amazinslider1">
  <ul class="amazingslider-slides">
      <li><img src="path/to/image"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And don't forget to add js before the end of `</head>`